# Remote process logs in local system

Tags: linux, logging, ubuntu-16.04

I have a process (for example `mongod`) that is running on the server and printing the logs continuously. I want these logs on my local system in real-time.

How can I achieve that? Is there any tool for this?

I am currently using Ubuntu and seeking guidance in Ubuntu also for the same.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to connect to your server and open your file in console using `tail`.

I assume that you can use `ssh` to connect to your server. Then you can try this:

```
tail -f "log_file_name"
```

It will refresh your logs every second (almost real time) and print them in your console.

EDIT:

You can also print your logs directly to file:

```
mongod > "log_file"
```

and then track this file using method above.

Comment: Do you want to track file? In what format are your logs? Are logs printed to your console o printed to log file? Your question doesn't answer any of this.

Comment: Please - update your question and don't use random pastebins. Also you have to specify where (what format) you want your logs on your machine. I'll update my answer with another idea, but be more precise.